# Fixing Unsuccessful Transaction on Payment Gateway using Midtrans (Android)

Tags: java, android, error-handling, payment-gateway

So I recently just trying to understand deeper into Payment Gateway (Android). I already read the documentation and try to implement it into my Android project. So here's the thing, couple times even until now, I'm always getting a message **"Transaction unsuccessful. Please try again with another card or with a different payment method"** when I try to click a button called **Pay**. So this **Pay** button when I clicked it, it supposed to open a new tab (page) to show all of the Payment Method. But again that page never showed up, and showing those errors only.

Can anyone help me fixing this problem? I'm gonna send u guys the code if u guys need it. BIG THANKS :)

Comment: Hello, please visit [SO Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/), read an article ["How to ask good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update your question with relevant details, and code.  Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is my button code looks like. How did I can get a page that showing **PaymentUiFlow** (Payment Method Page)? I already try to configure it out with many different ways but still showing the same error.

private void actionButton() {
        MidtransSDK.getInstance().setTransactionRequest(DataCustomer.transactionRequest(
                "1",
                getIntent().getIntExtra("price", 0),
                getIntent().getIntExtra("qty", 0),
                getIntent().getStringExtra("name")));
        MidtransSDK.getInstance().startPaymentUiFlow(ProductOrderActivity.this, PaymentMethod.BANK_TRANSFER_MANDIRI);
    }